# Download PDF using php with logo always on top of each page

Tags: php, pdf

I have this code to display on the page, however I also want to give users the option to download PDF , but on top of each PDF page I want there to be a logo picture, how can I do this? Is there a way with datatables? or just plain code?

```
<table>
<?php

foreach($sheets as $s):
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
$name= explode(' ',$s['customer_name'])
?>
<div style="text-align: center">
<img alt="" src="/adminpanel2/public/logo.png">
</div> 
<h2 style="text-align: center">Hi <?php echo $name[0] ?>!</h2>
    <div align="center">
   <br> Here is your delivery for: <br>
   <?php echo date('l, F dS', strtotime($s['delivery_week']));?>
   <br>
   ORDER NO. <?php echo $s['order_id'] ?>&nbsp; | &nbsp;  CUSTOMER NO.<?php echo $s['client_id'] ?>
   <hr style="height: 5px;border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-bottom:0px">
   <hr style="height: 5px;border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;">
   </div>
   <?php foreach($s['meals'] as $m):?>
   <h3><?php echo $m['display_name'];?> </h3>
   <?php echo $m['count']?> &nbsp; SERVING SHIPPED<br><br>
   COMPONENTS
   <hr align = "left" style="width: 115px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px">
   <br>
   <?php foreach($m['components'] as $c):?>
   <?php echo $c?><br>
   <?php endforeach;?>
   <hr align="left" style="width: 400px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px" >
   <?php endforeach;?>
   <hr align="left" style="width: 600px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px" >
   <div align="center"><h3> Thank you,<?php echo $name[0] ?>!</h3> 

    <hr style="width: 600px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px" >
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
    <br>
   <br>
    <br>
   </td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Here is my code (above) I am using php fuel

Comment: Well, you use any of the available PDF libraries for PHP and generate a PDF document holding whatever information you want. Then you send that document to the client as a result to a request. What is your question here?

Comment: Which PDF library is the best for me to be able to put a header on every page of the pdf without an issue @arkascha

Comment: Every PDF library can do that obviously, since they all allow to place arbitrary content in a document.